# How do I copy a custom real time document with Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to copy a realtime document that is integrated with google drive.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/drive
The docs say to use the "files" collection of the REST API but the copy method of the files collection is returning a 500 error

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
copied_file = {'title': 'copied file'}
drive_file = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=doc_id, body=copied_file).execute()
```

I tried putting my file Id on the sample drive page and it failed with a 500 internal error as well.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

Is it possible to copy a google real time document this way?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom drive file"? What error do you get when using the api?

Comment: I mean google real time documents that we integrate with google drive. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/drive. It says to use the "files" collection of the REST API but the copy method of the files collection is returning a 500 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy does not currently work for Realtime documents unfortunately.  We are working on a fix but it will be a little bit.

You can implement a psuedo-copy by creating a new file and using the [import/export](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/import-export) APIs to copy over the document contents.

Comment: Thanks. That was our fallback plan. At least I can stop looking now.

Comment: Do you know if this has been fixed yet?